# How to display interactive leaflet map in R notebook in colab

Tags: r, r-leaflet, jupyter-irkernel

I am unable to plot an interactive map in
[colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/ferroao/leaftest/blob/main/testCell.ipynb)

A workaround (static image) is in the second cell.

I expect an answer in r-leaflet.

Related [blog](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/04/r-htmlwidgets-in-jupyter-notebooks/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came with this answer/workaround - third cell in [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/ferroao/leaftest/blob/main/testCell.ipynb)

```
if (system.file(package = "leaflet") == '') {
  install.packages("leaflet")
}
if (system.file(package = "htmlwidgets") == '') {
  install.packages("htmlwidgets")
}
if (system.file(package = "IRdisplay") == '') {
  install.packages("IRdisplay")
}

library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(IRdisplay)

m = leaflet() %>% 
#addTiles() 
addTiles(urlTemplate = "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png") # colab compatibility

saveWidget(m, 'demo1.html', selfcontained = TRUE)

IaminColab<-TRUE

if(IaminColab){  # does not work in jupyter
  demo<-readLines("demo1.html")
  demo<-gsub("%","%25",demo)
  demo<-gsub("#","%23",demo)
  demo<-gsub("\"","%22",demo)
  demo<-gsub("'" ,"%27",demo)
  demo<-gsub("\\n" ,"",demo)
  demo<-paste(demo, collapse="")
  display_html(paste0('<iframe src=',"\"data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,",demo," \" height=\"300\" width=\"500\"></iframe>") )
} else { # does not work in colab
  display_html('<iframe src="demo1.html" width="500" height ="300"></iframe>')
}
```

[image]

Sources:
[Package leaflet - map doesn't show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812844/package-leaflet-map-doesnt-show)
[Convert HTML to data:text/html  link using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238890/convert-html-to-datatext-html-link-using-javascript)